# Jquery Show and hide banner on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, show-hide, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to show a banner scrolling over 1000px.
So, it works but I need to open and close it only one time.

[Here my complete demo](http://codepen.io/ASCARO/full/YpwVjQ/)

This is my .js

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) {
    $("#banner-promo").fadeIn("slow", function () {});

        }

       else {
            //  $('#BackToTop').css({'visibility': 'hidden'});
            $("#banner-promo").fadeOut("slow", function () {});
        }
  $("#chiudi").click(function(){
    $("#banner-promo").fadeOut("slow");
});
});
```

What's the best practice to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know that I understand. When I get to the bottom, I see the `fadeIn()`. Do you want it to no longer be able to scroll up and repeat this action? Why not change the `html { height }` back to `1000px`?

Comment: Why not treat it like a dialog box then. Set it's absolute position `top: 1000` and when the user scrolls down, they can then see it. When they click the button the element is removed or hidden.

Comment: hi @Twisty this is a banner to introduce a call to action on a web page: you can "Sign in" or "No thanks" by the buttons... anyway I wanna show it only one time when you scroll over 1000px and close it forever when you click on "No thanks".. Now if you close it by the button, it comes back again because you have still scrolled 1000px

Comment: @twisty mmm, yes.. maybe a right trick ... but without a nice fadein effect

Comment: You can still make use of `fadeIn` to show it, when they get down there. But removing it is key to ensuring it is not re-appearing. Or removing it;s selector. Something like `$("#banner-promo").attr("id", "banner-promo-closed");`

Comment: @Twisty  I don't know that I understand. Can you link me some examples please?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/0go8snsL/

Comment: @Twisty thanks man, I got the effect I wanted just adding        $("#banner-promo").remove();  thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, the answer you went with was to make use of `remove()` to take the element away versus hiding it.

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/0go8snsL/

`$("#banner-promo").remove();`

Comment: Sorry for late reply. But, the demo link is not working.

Comment: @Pupil the link to the fiddle appears to work. What are you seeing?